# Is Multi-Dash worth the cost?

Tags: hyper-light-drifter

Multi-Dash was the first perk I bought for the drifter, because I thought it was something which I could use to easily dodge enemmies. However, I can't get quite the hang of it, especially in fights. So in the end it feels rather useless and I feel like I could have invested the money into something more useful (HP, Sword attack, etc.).
I know that you need the multi dash to get to some secrets, but I am not that much of a treasure hunter anyway. 
So my questions are:

1. From a "fighting perspective" - is the Multi-Dash even worth it?
2. If not, what should I get?
3. Should I get the Multi-Dash at all if I do not intend to find all the secrets?

Answer (score 2):

It's absolutely required for some secrets, including outfits and modules (and in turn weapons).

It's almost entirely useless in combat. Go for all the sword upgrades there, then the dash ones.

Comment: Considering you can upgrade dash to deflect ranged attacks, multi dash makes you nearly invincible to ranged attackers and turrets.